# Understanding top level get() in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

While I was checking this [repository](https://github.com/mlykotom/connecting-the-dots-sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mlykotom/connectingthedots/ConnectingTheDotsApp.kt) about dagger in android with kotlin, I stumbled upon the application class:

```
class ConnectingTheDotsApp : Application() {
    val appComponent: AppComponent by lazy {
        DaggerAppComponent
            .factory()
            .create(this)
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appComponent.inject(this)
    }
}

val Activity.appComponent get() = (application as ConnectingTheDotsApp).appComponent
val Fragment.appComponent get() = (requireActivity().application as ConnectingTheDotsApp).appComponent
```

The class I understand. But the two last lines of code, I cannot figure them out. I know that `get()` is a backing property but why is it outside a class and what about the `Activity.` and `Fragment.` what did they mean? Any Idea? 
Thanks

Comment: [extension-properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-properties)

Comment: That's right! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mind guys. As [IR42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12191177/ir42) stated, it's just a simple implementation of the extension properties in koltin.